# Is there a R function that tests for existence of more than one specified objects?

Tags: r, object, exists

So i know in R, there is `exists()` which can tell whether an object exists in the environment.

What I want to test though, is the existence of multiple objects, say `a, b, c` in R.

Is there a function that can do something like `exists(c('a','b','c'))` in R and return FALSE if any one of the objects does not exist?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can write your own function like this:

```
exists.m <- function(x) {
  all(sapply(x, exists))
}


exists.m(c("mean", "sd"))
[1] TRUE
```

otherwise, more convenient approach is to use `...` as argument in function.

```
exists.m <- function(...) {
  ls <- list(...)
  all(sapply(ls, exists))
}

exists.m("mean", "sd")
[1] TRUE
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `ls()` to check if the object exists in the environment.

```
a <- 1
b <- 2

all(c('a', 'b', 'c') %in% ls())
#[1] FALSE

all(c('a', 'b') %in% ls())
#[1] TRUE
```